# How to calculate AIC of a spatial panel model in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, goodness-of-fit, aic, spatial

This may be a better question for Stack Overflow, but I think a statistics answer may be warranted here:

I have built some spatial panel models in `R` using the package `splm`. These models include the following options:

- Random-effects (via `model = "random"`)
- No spatial error (via `spatial.error = "none"`)
- A lag term (via `lag = TRUE`)

I would like to compare their fit using AIC, but upon running the `AIC()` function in `R`, I am returned the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('splm', 'splm_ML')"
```

notably, a spatial panel model of the class `splm` has the following information:

```
str(spatial_panel)
List of 15
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 4.55 -1.84
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "value"
 $ arcoef       : Named num 0.423
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lambda"
 $ errcomp      : Named num 45.9
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "phi"
 $ vcov         : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.0104 -0.027 -0.027 0.2797
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "value"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "value"
 $ vcov.arcoef  : num [1, 1] 0.00352
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "lambda"
  .. ..$ : chr "lambda"
 $ vcov.errcomp : num [1, 1] 92.4
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "phi"
  .. ..$ : chr "phi"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:267] 3.78 3.78 2.63 2.6 2.67 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:267] "1" "4" "7" "10" ...
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:267] 4.55 3.02 4.41 4.53 4.52 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:267] "1" "4" "7" "10" ...
 $ sigma2       :List of 3
  ..$ one  : num 0.706
  ..$ idios: num 0.0151
  ..$ id   : num 0.691
 $ model        :'data.frame':  267 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ y : num [1:267] 8.32 6.8 7.03 7.13 7.19 ...
  ..$ V2: num [1:267] 0.00244 0.83328 0.07858 0.01049 0.01663 ...
 $ type         : chr "random effects ML"
 $ type.des     : chr "ML panel with spatial lag, random effects"
 $ call         : language spreml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, w = listw2mat(listw),      w2 = listw2mat(listw2), lag = la| __truncated__
 $ errors       : chr "re"
 $ logLik       : num -43.5
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "splm" "splm_ML"
```

Are there alternative methods to compare the fit between these models? Or is there a way I can calculate AIC using the information stored in the model output?